# Is it possible to "countif" cell contain value of specific order?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I work on a warehouse using WM apps that resulting exported data for daily transaction. We use **open office calc** for spreadsheet data processing. The data contain cells for location, with format like:

```
01.001.1.1 for 1st level of racking
01.001.2.1 for 2nd level of racking
01.001.3.1 for 3rd level of racking, etc until 7th level of racking
```

I want to count how many daily transaction for 1st and 2nd level, and separate it for 3rd to 7th level racking.

Can I use `countif`or `frequency` or another formula to do this?

Comment: You can use an assist column. The assist column would have something like =MID(cellselection,8,1) and then use your countif formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single formula, or by using a helper column as @Eric suggested.  This formula, filled down from C3 in the table below, lists the level of each location:

`=MID(A3,8,1)`

and this one in D3 counts the number of 1st and 2nd levels in the list:

`=COUNTIF(C3:C12,1)+COUNTIF(C3:C12,2)`

This formula in B3 will also return the number of 1st and 2nd levels:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1*(VALUE(MID(A3:A12,8,1))<3))`

[image]
**____________________________________________________________________**

In the last formula, `MID()` returns an array of the level numbers, but these are in quotes, so Excel treats them as text.

`VALUE()` converts the array back to numbers, making the test for `< 3` valid, and this gives an array of `True/False` values with `True` wherever the level is 1 or 2.

Multiplying this array by 1 converts the `True/False` values into 1's and 0's, and `SUMPRODUCT()` sums the array, giving the total number of 1st and 2nd levels.

Comment: hai @Bandersnatch, thanks for your answer, it works as the best solution for me. But can we expand that to a wider formula? I want to determine location type by location number. for example 01.001.1.1 - 02.028.7.2 as SPR, 30.001.1 - 31.024.5 as VNA, and M01.01.1A - M02.24.5B as MULTITIER?

Comment: Yes, but some questions: If the location starts with "M", is it Multitier? If the first 2 digits are 30 or 31, is it VNA? If they are 01 or 02, is it SPR? And are there any locations that are **not** in the ranges you've written?

Comment: actually there are 5 location type: 01.001.1.1 - 30.027.7.2 (30 odd rack) is SPR, 30.002.1(30 even rack)  - 33.024.5 is VNA, location start with M is MULTITIER, location start with CL (CL.01.01 - CL.08.05) is CANTILEVER, and location start with FL (FL01 - FL30) is FLOOR. The difference between odd and even rack in 30 is the location format, 30.001.1.1 and 30.002.1 (both are 1st level), or 30.001.5.1 and 30.002.5 (both are 5th level).

Comment: @bl4ckbox, what you describe sounds like another layer of complexity.  Trying to incorporate that into this answer may create a lot of confusion for other readers looking for the answer to the question presented here.  It would be much better to post that as a new question, and then get an answer specific to that.

Comment: Good point, @fix.  Howya doin? :-)

Comment: okay all.. thankyou so much for all of your response.. cheerss